# liquibase DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK read-only error

Tags: database, jhipster, liquibase

I am having a problem with liquibase and the databasechangeloglock table. It always gives me this error when starting jhipster via gradle:

```
liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Table 'databasechangeloglock' is read only [Failed SQL: INSERT INTO db.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK (ID, LOCKED) VALUES (1, 0)]
```

I am using a local mysql database. Can somebody help me? I can't get this to work. Even tried to create a new database but the error stays.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide examples of your code that is causing the issues

Comment: You have to provide your code here in the question to get help on Stackoverflow.